# I am struggling to set up OpenGL and GLAD

Tags: c++, error-handling, codeblocks, glfw, opengl-3

I am reading a book called learn OpenGL and I am struggling with the set up. I am using code blocks. What I have done so far is:
I downloaded the 32 bit binaries for GLFW from this website: http://www.glfw.org/download.html
I also downloaded GLAD from this website:
http://glad.dav1d.de/ 
I then added all the files from these downloads to an include folder. After this I added glad.c and glad.h to my project. Then in codeblocks I clicked the project tab then went to build options - search directories - compiler and added the 2 include folders that I got from the downloads and the src folder. Then in search directories I went to linker and added lib-mingw.

The book I am reading told me to add this code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
//setting the version of openGL
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

//creating a window
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
if (window = NULL)
{
    std::cout <<"Failed to create GLFW window\n";
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
return -1;
}

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

return 0;
}
```

My problem is I keep getting the error: 'GLADloadproc' was not declared in this scope and 'GLADLoadGLLoader' was not declared in this scope. Also I have tried putting the glad folder into my project file directory so that the `#include <glad/glad.h>` can be found. What could be the problem?

Comment: The code you embedded here doesn't `#include <glad/glad.h>`

Comment: yes I know but the line #include <glad/glad.h> is part of glad.c

Comment: @adamtheguy762 But you haven't included it in **the above file** which is where you are getting the errors. You are supposed to include `glad.h` in every file that uses the functions defined in `glad.c`. That's how header files work.

Comment: yes I tried adding #include <glad/glad.h> to main but it gave me the error: No such file or directory.

Comment: Also I dont know if I should be adding #include <glad/glad.h> or just  #include <glad.h>.

Comment: @adamtheguy762 Well that's the problem, your project isn't set up correctly to find the file. Whether you should say `#include <glad/glad.h>` or `#include <glad.h>` is best answered by looking at the GLAD documentation.

Comment: @adamtheguy762 Looking at your description I get the impression (I might be wrong) that you are trying to put GLAD and OpenGL in your project. That's not correct. You should be installing OpenGL and GLAD on your system in some location that is **independent** of your project. You should then build them (if necessary, not sure about that). Only then create your project and refer to the existing installation locations from your project. OpenGL and GLAD are not part of your project, they are referred to by your project. This requires good understanding or your OS, your IDE and OpenGL and GLAD

Comment: Ok but I have tried both and niether have worked

Comment: Where can I find the GLAD documentation? Also, making the assumption I have the correct include for glad (because I dont think that is the problem as I have tried both), what other suggestions do you have?

Comment: Here? https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_.28Multi-Language_GL.2FGLES.2FEGL.2FGLX.2FWGL_Loader-Generator.29, it says `<glad/glad.h>`

Comment: @john It's perfectly fine to just have the GLAD files in the project folder since the header is usually tailored per project.

Comment: @adamtheguy762 You need to understand how codeblocks  works. Including 3rd party libraries in projects is a common requirement. Just read the documentation and find out how to do it. Sorry but I don't know codeblocks myself.

Comment: @Fibbles OK I stand corrected.

Comment: Ok thanks I @john I will try reading the documentation

Comment: @adamtheguy762 If your code::blocks project is in folder `my_project` the the GLAD files should be placed like  `/my_project/glad/glad.h`. You also need to add all GLAD files the to the project in code:: blocks. Usually you right click on the file tree on the left and choose 'add files recursively'. Lastly in each source or header file where you make use of Open GL or you include a library that uses OpenGL make sure you have either `#include "glad/glad.h"` or `#include <glad/glad.h>`. It needs to be included before anything else. Thats not the definitive way to set it up but it's the easiest.

Comment: @Fibbles I have tried including #include <glad/glad.h> in my source file but it gave me an error that said that the header had already been included. Also I have placed all the files in my_project (well not the same name but I have done it). Also I have added glad.c and glad.h to the project.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you include the same file twice since they have header guards. I can only guess at this point to be honest. Maybe Code::Blocks is getting confused due to your include paths and is seeing multiple options for `glad/glad.h`. Try using `#include "glad/glad.h"`? That'll check your project directory first. If that doesn't work you'll have to read through the Code::Blocks docs for setting up include paths and check that against your project.

Comment: ok thanks for the help anyway